# How to count sets of specific characters in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

Basically, I want to count sets of specific characters in a string.
In other words I need to count all Letters and Numbers, and nothing else.
But I cant seem to find the right (regex) syntax.
Here's what i have ...

```
public double AlphaNumericCount(string s)
{
    double count = Regex.Matches(s, "[A-Z].[a-z].[0-9]").Count;
        return count;
}
```

I've been looking around, but cant seem to find anything that allows more than one set of characters.
Again, I'm not sure on the syntax maybe it should be
    "[A-Z]/[a-z]/[0-9]"
or something. Anywho, go easy on me - its my first day using Regex.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[Regular Expression Cheat Sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

[Expresso Regular Expression tool](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)

`[A-Z].[a-z].[0-9]` will match any capital letter (`[A-Z]`), followed by any character (`.`), followed by any lower case letter (`[a-z]`), followed by any character (`.`), followed by any number (`[0-9]`).

What you want to match on any letter or number is `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

Answer (score 4):

If the use of regular expressions is not required, there is an easy, alternate solution:

```
return s.ToCharArray().Count(c => Char.IsNumber(c) || Char.IsLetter(c));
```

Comment: `ToCharArray()` is not necessary here. `string` already implements `IEnumerable<char>`

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

see: [regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1014)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid regular expressions, you can simply iterate through the characters in the string and check if they're a letter or digit using [Char.IsLetterOrDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletterordigit.aspx).

```
public int AlphaNumericCount(string s)
{
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
       if(Char.IsLetterOrDigit(s[i])) 
          count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Regex might look neater but, depending on the length of the string/number of calls, they *may* be slower.